# Stop Visual Studio 2019 from automatically adding comment prefix when enter pressed?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I can't find the option to turn of the VS2019 editor from automatically continuing a comment to the next line.  Example:

```
// This is my comment and when I press enter it gives me:
//
```

I don't want it to add the // on enter.  Where do I turn that off?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any extensions like Visual Assist installed?

Comment: No, I have Word highlight with margin (just added it) so that's not it, live share [disabled], start page+, BCGAppWizard2019, Test Adapter for Google Test, Test Adapter for Boost.Test, Visual Studio IntelliCode,NuGetRecommender,  Visual Studio Rich Navigation, Visual Studion Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> General and uncheck "Insert existing comment style at the start of new lines when writing comments"

Comment: Very annoying feature, in MSVC 2022 they changed its name to "Automatic brace completion"

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in [Visual Studio 2019 16.9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-1690).  You can disable it in **Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced** (or search for "comments") by unchecking `Insert // at the start of new lines when writing // comments`.

[image]

Comment: I'm using C/C++ but I still tried turning it off for C# but didn't work.  I noticed sometimes I can type \\ test and enter without adding extra but when in between comments like \\ line1 \\line2 and press enter after line1 it adds it to the new blank line between line1 and line2

Comment: Ah. I don't have the C++ SDK installed for VS right now so I can't check, but is there a similar option under **Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced** for inserting // at the start of new lines?

Comment: I didn't see one, but I may be missing it?